# Can someone remotely get into my computer and make it look like I typed something in a search?

Tags: malware

Is it possible for someone to remotely manipulate the keys on my computer to make it look like I was typing?

Comment: Can you please clarify more about what scenario of security breach you are asking about?

Comment: Oh, come on, Marie. No matter what you say, your mother won't believe you. We all know you're the one who was Googling for _that_.

Comment: @Adnan lol took the work straight outta my mouth

Answer (score 1):

Most desktop remote tools or in a more malicious method through a Remote Administration Tool normally allow the user to use both a mouse and keyboard for input.

To put it bluntly, yes someone could infect your computer and perform a web search which would appear to have been from your PC & IP.

Comment: They wouldn't need to use your browser either, or even your computer (depending on your home router): If they have access to your local network they could use ARP poisoning to pretend to be your computer and send HTTP search requests as your computer.

Comment: But it would not appear in the history of the user's browser.